# How do I allow another player in my world?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

We are connected to the same Internet but when we try to join each other's worlds it says 'invalid name'.

We are using the update with boats that can fit 2 people.

Comment: Since when do boats fit 2 people?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with the latest update as so many duplicate questions are being asked.

To fix it: Wait until the next update.

Comment: Instead of telling them that it is a duplicate, click 'flag' > is a duplicate of..... > select question

Comment: I did that as well